# problem in file upload

Tags: php

If the file name is `fin's xyz.mp3` then it is not uploading because of this fin(')s  single quote. How should I use `move_uploaded_file($tmp,$dest)` in PHP?

Example:

```
$name1=$_FILES['FileName']['name'];
$tmp1=$_FILES['FileName']['tmp_name'];
$target = "../music_files/";
$up=uniqid().$name1;
$target = $target.$up;
move_uploaded_file($tmp1,$target);
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="loginfrm" onsubmit="return CheckLogin();">
    <input type="file" id="FileName" name="FileName" class="text-box" />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us more code? How are you handling the file upload? What are `$tmp` and `$dest`?

Comment: @anuradha - could you try formatting your code so it's easier to read? Indent each line of code by four spaces.

Comment: Edit your code using the markdown buttons. It's difficult reading your code.

Comment: @anuradha you can click edit and edit your original post to add new code so it has readable formatting.  :-)

Comment: My guess is FileName is not the field defined in your form.  Do you have <input type="file" name="FileName" /> in your code?

Comment: $name1=$_FILES['FileName']['name']; 
$tmp1=$_FILES['FileName']['tmp_name']; 
$target = "../music_files/"; 
$up=uniqid().$name1; 
$target = $target.$up; 
move_uploaded_file($tmp1,$target);

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php has some info in the comments on quotes causing problems

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are storing the file you can strip all non alpha-numeric characters with a simple [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) and then you do not have to worry about it.

```
$name1 = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9_-]~i', '', $_FILES['FileName']['name']);
```

Pending I did not make any silly mistakes.

If you are storing the name in a database you can just make the actual filename an md5 hash and reference that in the table you store the information in.

Comment: ya i m storing the file name in database since file name is fin's xyz.mp3 i m using addslashes in insert query but file is not getting uploaded in the  say "../music_files/ dir bzs of single quote

Answer (score 0):

Quotes serve as special characters on many systems - you might want to sanitize your filenames - e.g. whitelist a set of characters and drop the others:

```
$name1=$_FILES['FileName']['name'];
$up=uniqid() . preg_preplace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/','',$name1);
```

This gives you, as a bonus, added resiliency against invalid filenames and directory traversal attacks (e.g. where an attacker would give "../../../../../../../../etc/passwd" as the file's name).